# How can I perform a function when the page shows or the app launches in React Native

Tags: react-native

In React Native, how can I perform a function when the page shows or any component shows, this really confuses me a lot, I can't find the solution in the Documents, and I use functions to declare the components.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class component and and call your function in the componentDidMount lifecycle method

Answer (score 0):

use can also use hook instead of componentDidMount, I personally find code more readable with hooks

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
const Component = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        //do anything here
     }, [])

     return(
         //JSX
     )
}
```